# Installed SideWaffle in VS2013 but don't see templates in NewProject dialog?

Tags: angularjs, templates, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials, sidewaffle

I just installed SideWaffle along with WebEssentials 4 into my Visual Studio 2013 installation.  I do see SideWaffle and WebEssentials 4 in the list of installed Extensions when I check Tools -> Extensions and Updates.  However, when I do either a New Project or New Web Site attempt, I do *not* see any SideWaffle templates to choose from.  I also used the search box with the keyword SideWaffle and still don't see anything.  I definitely restarted VS2013 after doing the SideWaffle install.  No luck.  Oddly enough, I don't see any items related to AngularJS either.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you see any of the item templates? Are you using C# or VB?

Comment: @KentCooper I'm at a loss to explain this, but after a recent recommended update by the VS2013 message notifications drop-down, the SideWaffle templates magically started showing up when I do File -> New Project under Templates -> Visual C# -> Web.  They didn't before the update.

Comment: Oh glad its working! Hope you enjoy the templates.